# Did Catherine the Great die of injuries from a horse?

Tags: history, zoology, sexuality

Perhaps I have been reading the wrong kind of scurrilous literature, but I have seen it asserted that the Empress Catherine the Great of Russia died from injuries received by committing unnatural acts with a stallion. Is there any truth in this assertion?

Comment: I applaud you for expressing this question without the need to tell us the graphic details.  Well done!

Comment: A link to a notable source making that claim, or even to an example of *the wrong kind of scurrilous literature*, would be helpful.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This claim doesn't seem to have any factual underpinning; none of the [books about Catherine the Great](http://www.amazon.co.uk/s/?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=catherine+the+great) support it. While I haven't read any of them, I did read the reviews on Amazon, and none mentioned such an event; some reviewers [specifically point out](http://www.amazon.co.uk/review/R3G9S47RL0NFRS/ref=cm_cr_rdp_perm?ie=UTF8&ASIN=0099462346&nodeID=&tag=&linkCode=) that there are no records of Catherine the Great having equine sex partners.

In addition, a number of other on-line resources discuss this issue, and all come to the same conclusion, that this rumor is false.

From [europeanhistory.about.com](http://europeanhistory.about.com/od/catherinethegreat/a/histmyths1.htm):

> [Alexander's book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Catherine-Great-Legend-Oxford-Lives/dp/0195061624/ref=sr_1_5?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1310164938&sr=1-5) goes on to explain
>   (in paragraphs rarely quoted) how
>   Catherine was laid in her bed as
>   doctors tried to save her body and
>   priests made rites to save her soul.
>   Throughout she was racked with pain,
>   her convulsing appearance causing
>   great distress to her consorts. It was
>   over twelve hours after Zotov found
>   her, well past nine o'clock at night,
>   that **Catherine finally died of natural
>   causes, in bed and surrounded by
>   friends and carers**.

From [The Straight Dope](http://www.straightdope.com/columns/read/100/is-it-true-about-catherine-the-great-and-the-horse):

> The simple answer to your question is
>   no, the rumor is not true. However,
>   that won't stop us from repeating the
>   rumor, to wit: that Catherine the
>   Great, empress of Russia in the latter
>   part of the 18th century, was crushed
>   to death when attendants lost their
>   grip on ropes supporting a horse that
>   was being lowered on her for, ah,
>   sexual purposes. This is without doubt
>   the most outrageous story I heard
>   during my entire college career, which
>   is when you usually come across these
>   historical tidbits.
>
> The boring truth is this: **Catherine
>   the Great died of a stroke while
>   sitting on the commode in the palace
>   at St. Petersburg.** Another less
>   commonly circulated rumor has it that
>   Catherine was so grossly fat (true in
>   itself) that she broke the commode and
>   died of blood loss from resultant
>   injuries, but this is regarded as a
>   fabrication also.

From [Snopes.com](http://www.snopes.com/risque/animals/catherine.asp):

> **Catherine the Great actually expired
>   alone and of natural causes.** On the
>   morning of 5 November 1796, Catherine
>   arose, drank coffee, and sat down to
>   write. About three hours later her
>   chamberlain, curious that he had not
>   been summoned as usual, found her
>   barely conscious on the floor of a
>   closet adjacent to her bedroom. As her
>   servant summoned help, Catherine
>   lapsed into unconsciousness from which
>   she never awakened and died at 9:45 PM
>   the next day. **An autopsy conducted the
>   next day determined the cause of death
>   to be a cerebral hemorrhage.**

I think it is safe to conclude that there is not a single speck of truth in the assertion.

Answer (score 9):

Short answer is **NO, NOT True.**

Straight Dope has a good though un-sourced article on it: http://www.straightdope.com/columns/read/100/is-it-true-about-catherine-the-great-and-the-horse

Actual details of death (In bed, after a stroke) can be found, for example, in this book:

Rounding, Virginia (2007) "Catherine the Great: Love, Sex, and Power" (New York: St. Martin’s Press ISBN 9780312328870), pages 499-502

The reason the rumors are easy to believe is that she did, admittedly, lead a very active sexual life, taking many young lovers up to pretty advanced age. Wiki has all the sordid and not so sordid details.